# Memory leak detection tool in Cygwin

Tags: c, linux, memory-leaks, cygwin, memory-leak-detector

I am scouting for a memory leak detection tool in cygwin. What could be the best memory leak detection tool for a C application in cygwin ?

Comment: There seems to be a [duplicate of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11811356/memory-leak-tool-on-cygwin).

Comment: True. I too came across that link before posting this query. It appears as a pretty old status and i believe that things should have changed/evolved by now. Also, the answers do not seem to point to a definite or best memory leak tool.

Answer (score 1):

Allegedly you can use `dmalloc` under Cygwin: http://dmalloc.com/docs/5.4.3/online/dmalloc_18.html